# How to style a database input with Bootstrap

Tags: css, mysql, sql, database

I have a question about bootstrap and database inputs

I have this database table:

```
CREATE TABLE `settings` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `name` varchar(64) NOT NULL default '',
  `value` text NOT NULL,
  `box_type` enum('textbox','input','checkbox','hidden','select','radio') NOT NULL default 'textbox',
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  `cat` enum('Paramètres de votre site','Email générés sur inscription et mots de passes perdus','Inscription','Paiement','OTO (Offre Unique)','Sécurité','PapillonMarketing Affiliation','Répondeur automatique','Statistiques','Réglages Downline','Partenariat JV','Activation Codes') NOT NULL default 'Paramètres de votre site',
  `rank` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `name` (`name`),
  KEY `cat` (`cat`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COMMENT='Settings table' AUTO_INCREMENT=3329 ;
```

When I insert data like this:

```
INSERT INTO `settings` (`id`, `name`, `value`, `box_type`, `description`, `cat`, `rank`) 
VALUES (136, 'sales_email', '', 'input', 'Your email here.', 'Site parameters', 0);
```

**The result:** I get a normal html input. So can you please tell me how to add Bootstrap css `class="form-control"` to this input?

Thank you :-)

Comment: How does the database record become an HTML element?

Answer (score 0):

I tested something that works!

I copied Bootstrap css for form-control and put it in  like this:

input {
    (form-control css here)
}

It works fine :)